# How to create directed graph of values by timestamp

Tags: r, plot, graph, timestamp

I have a dataset:

```
group        status                 timestamp
  1        create new          2019-04-26 12:37:11.520000000
  1        ready for test      2019-04-26 13:44:11.140000000
  1        test                2019-04-26 13:45:12.990000000
  1        done                2019-04-26 13:51:11.660000000

  2        update              2019-04-26 12:37:11.520000000
  2        ready for update    2019-04-26 13:44:11.140000000
  2        test                2019-04-26 13:45:12.990000000
  2        done                2019-04-26 13:51:11.660000000
```

I want to create the directed graph of status's by timestamp by group (so arrow goes from status to create new, then from create new to ready for test and so on). So here must be 2 groups and number of graphs is same as number of groups. How to do that? Should I use bupaR library?

Answer (score 0):

(Edited) Perhaps there is no need to make this a graph. Simple tidyverse will get you this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)



t1 <- 
  tibble(group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
            status = c("create new","ready for test", "test", "done", "update", "ready for update", "test", "done"), 
            timestamp = structure(c(1556282231.52, 1556286251.14, 1556286312.99, 1556286671.66, 1556282231.52, 1556286251.14, 1556286312.99, 1556286671.66), 
                                  class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"))

t1 %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% mutate(seq = row_number()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = timestamp, y = 1,
             colour = status)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = status), direction = "y") +
    geom_path(aes(group = group), arrow = arrow(type = "closed", length = unit(2, units = "mm")), alpha = 0.5) + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
    facet_wrap(~group, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to make it look more like a graph with vertices names on them and better visualization, because when I apply it to bigger data with more groups text covers each other. also text values ​​on the y-axis cover each other

Comment: Try the new code. You can try turning this into a graph object with igraph if the simple tidyverse approach does not work.